# History of the Jaccard distance $d(A,B) = \mathbb P(\overline A\cup\overline B\mid A\cup B)$

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, mg.metric-geometry, real-analysis, ho.history-overview

I'm wondering where the *relative probabilistic distance* or Jaccard distance was first studied:
$$d(A,B) =\mathbb P(\overline A\cup\overline B\mid A\cup B)$$
where $\overline A$ is the complement of $A$.

A web search turned up this:

```
@TechReport{Yianilos91,
  author =   "Peter N. Yianilos",
  title =    "Normalized Forms for Two Common Metrics",
  institution =  "NEC Research Institute",
  year =     {1991,2002}
}
```

which contains a detailed proof that  $d $ obeys the triangle inequality, but surely that was discovered prior to 1991?

On a seemingly related note, Cathy O'Neil mentions at 5:00 in *Deciphering recommendation engines*, http://youtu.be/lzavwJy1SgQ that 
$$\mathbb P(A\mid A\cup B)$$
is a mathematically interesting notion of closeness.

Comment: I am puzzling by the terminology *distance*. If $B=A$, don't we have $d(A,B)={\mathbb P}(\bar A|A)=0$ ?

Comment: @DenisSerre Yes, that's right

Comment: It is also Exercise 8.4.1(b) in Li and Vitanyi's book Kolmogorov complexity and its applications, 3rd edition.

Comment: Is it known when / how it got that [name](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_Jaccard#Contributions_en_mathématiques)?

Answer (score 4):

If I remember correctly, it was by Menger, in this series of papers.

Menger, 1942(12), [statistical metrics](http://www.pnas.org/content/28/12/535.full.pdf+html), *PNAS* 28(12):535-537.

Menger, 1951(3), [probabilistic theory of relations](http://www.pnas.org/content/37/3/178.full.pdf+html), *PNAS* 37(3):178-180.

Menger, 1951(4), [probabilistic geometry](http://www.pnas.org/content/37/4/226.full.pdf+html), *PNAS* 37(4):226-229.

Menger et al, 1959(au), [probabilistic metrics and numerical metrics with probability](http://dml.cz/bitstream/handle/10338.dmlcz/100370/CzechMathJ_09-1959-3_12.pdf), *czechoslovakian mathematical journal* 9(3):459-466.

If each pair of coordinates points is supposed to nowhere exist strictly a distance $x$ apart, for all possible $x$, and they only have a probability $z$ of being separated by such a distance (or by a lesser distance), then special cases exist, one per distinguishable $x$:---probabilities for one and only one $x$ are defined in each case and undefined for other distances. There the $z$ corresponding to each pair of points is itself FAPP a distance between any two such points. From each such metric, at most one further constraint is required for a metric of the sort in the question title to result.

[The formal part of this answer, I agree it needs rewriting, temporarily gone. Also, I'm checking another possible source, slightly more recent, where the desired metric is explicitly stated unless my memory is wrong.]

Comment: It's not quite the same thing but closely related in the way above, worth citing. I also am looking for the metric you mentioned in Eddington's *Fundamental Theory*, because I remember seeing it there explicitly (but I could be wrong):---if it's there, I'll update my answer again with the chapter.

Comment: I've summarized the basic idea. BTW, I agree, the (1) (2) (3) edit needed rewriting (and correction, as one of the conditions to reduce to the special case was unnecessary, I now think).

Comment: OK thanks, looking forward to any further details

Comment: Only got around to it today, still checking. Two publications to check, one from 1969, one from 1946.